# Upper semicontinuity of a probability measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, limits

Let $m$ be an atomless probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Consider $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $x \mapsto f(x,v)$ is continuous.

Define the function $F: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow [0,1]$ as 
$$ F(x) := m\left( \{ w \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid f(x,w) \geq 0 \}\right). $$

I am wondering if $F$ is upper semicontinuous, i.e. for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\lim \sup_{ x_n \rightarrow x } F(x_n ) \leq F(x) $.

If not, I am looking for a counterexample.

Also, I am wondering if $m$ being atomless is really needed.

I started as follows.

$\lim \sup_{ x_n \rightarrow x } m\left( \{ w \in \mathbb{R}^m \mid f(x_n,w)\geq 0 \}\right) = \lim \sup_{ x_n \rightarrow x } \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \mathbb{1}_{ \{ w \mid f(x_n, w) \geq 0 \}}(w) m(dw) \leq^{ \text{Fatou} } \ \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \lim \sup_{ x_n \rightarrow x } \mathbb{1}_{ \{ w \mid f(x_n, w) \geq 0 \} }(w) m(dw) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m}  \mathbb{1}_{ \lim \sup_{ x_n \rightarrow x } \{ w \mid f(x_n, w)\geq 0 \} }(w) m(dw) $.

Then I do not know if I can move $\lim \sup_{ x_n \rightarrow x }$ "inside the set", namely getting $ \{ w \mid \lim \sup_{ x_n \rightarrow x } f( x_n,w ) \} $.

Getting to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \limsup_{x_n \rightarrow x} \mathbb{1}_{ \{w \mid f(x_n,w)\geq 0 \} }(w) m(dw) $, a way of thinking may be to define the sets $A_n := \{w \mid f(x_n,w) \geq 0 \}$ and claim that for all $w \in \mathbb{R}^m$ it holds $\limsup_{x_n \rightarrow x} \mathbb{1}_{A_n}(w) \leq \mathbb{1}_A(w)$.

Comment: Your function $g$ should be $f$; and according to the definition of $F$, you should put "$\geq 0$" instead of "$>0$". However, your claim is indeed correct, with $A_n=\{ w; f(x_n,w)\geq 0\}$ and $A=\{ w; f(x,w)\geq 0\}$: if a point $w$ belongs to infinitely many $A_n$, then $w\in A$ by continuity of $u\mapsto f(u,w)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Can you please be a bit more detailed about your statement? So we define $A_n := \{ w \mid f(x_n,w)\geq0 \}$ and $A := \{ w \mid f(x,w) \geq 0 \}$. Then we need to show that $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} A_n  \subseteq A$. How?

Comment: Take $w\in\limsup A_n$. This means that $w$ is in infinitely many $A_n$; that is, $f(x_n,w)\geq 0$ for infinitely many $n$. Since $x_n\to x$, it follows that $f(x,w)\geq 0$ by the continuity assumption.

Comment: Thanks again. I understand that your claim is the following. "Fix any $w$. If $f(x_n,w) \geq 0$ for infinitely many $n$ then $f(x,w) \geq 0$ because of the continuity". However, I am looking for a formal proof. In the other words, can you please explain where is the continuity assumption used?

Comment: You have an increasing sequence $(n_k)$ such that $f(x_{n_k},w)\geq 0$ for all $k$; and since the map $z\mapsto f(z,w)$ is continuous and $x_{n_k}\to x$, you also have $f(x,w)=\lim f(x_{n_k},w)$. So $f(x,w)\geq 0$.

Comment: So why the same argument does not apply if $f(x,w)>0$ instead of $\geq 0$?

Comment: Because strict inequalities are not preserved under limits.